can we use css path on environment base in the css file in angular
I have to base path in angular  and for css file i add the base path into css file but while running local no base path and it give error.
$vf-font-plex-mono-prefix: '/baseHref/assets/fonts';
$vf-font-plex-sans-prefix: '/baseHref/assets/fonts';

baseHref on local is not working and get error while running locally
